# Server returning 500 error when using WebRequest to get XML document

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, xmldocument

Here is my code to get the xml document from a url that is passed in.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    request.ContentLength = 0;

                    var response = request.GetResponse(); // Error is thrown here
```

When I copy and paste the url into my browser it works just fine.

Here is the complete xml that is returned

```
<Model>
   <Item>
     <Id>7908</Id>
   </Item>
</Model>
```

Is the xml in an incorrect format? I have tried changing the content type to be application/xml but I still get this error.

EDIT=======================================================

I am trying to use webclient using this code:

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Headers["Method"] = "GET";
                    wc.Headers["ContentType"] = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
                    wc.Headers["Accept"] = "text/xml, */*";
                    wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;)";
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-us";
                    wc.Headers["KeepAlive"] = "true";
                    wc.Headers["AutomaticDecompression"] = (DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip).ToString();

                    var response = wc.DownloadString(url);
                }
```

The response string is empty!!! Any ideas why this is not returning any result but pasting the url into the browser returns the xml?

Comment: What does the rest of the error message say?

Comment: "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

Comment: You need to turn on detailed error messages so you can get the full error message and stack trace.  There's not enough info to diagnose your problem without it.

Comment: I am getting this exception while I debug my c# code. I have tried catching the WebException but it just contains information about the request but no indication of why it returned a 500 error.

Comment: Have a look at http://fixunix.com/tcp-ip/66198-http-rfc-related-question-content-length-0-get-request.html.  As I understand it, you really should not have a content length header at all on a GET request. If you omit the line that sets `request.ContentLength = 0`, the default value is -1, indicating that no content length header should be sent.

Comment: Try using a debugging proxy (like http://fiddler2.com/) to compare the bad request with the good request.  You can use Fiddler's "Request Builder" tool to manually tweak the request until you find which header is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working. I had to use this code:

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Headers["Method"] = "GET";
                    wc.Headers["Accept"] = "application/xml";

                    var response = wc.DownloadString(url);
                }
```

The key was using the accept header of "application/xml" otherwise the response would come back empty.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a WebClient instead.

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request.GetType() == typeof(HttpWebRequest)){
            ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.17 Safari/537.36";
        }
        return request;
    }
}

using(var wc = new MyWebClient()){
    var response = wc.DownloadString(url);
    //do stuff with response
}
```

Comment: Only other thing i can think of is changing the user agent. Updated with example.

Comment: I updated my question and I have added the user agent and other headers but nothing is returned in the response variable. Do I have to seek to the beginning or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully do the trick:

```
try 
{
  using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
    // Do things
  }
}
catch(WebException e)
{
   // Handled!...
}
```

Try what Joel Lee suggested if this fails.